# Weird see through geometry in orthographic view

Tags: rendering, normals, orthographic

I'm importing an object into blender and for some reason it looks fine when in perspective view but as soon as I switch to orthographic view some of the faces disappear/are rendered weird. I thought it might be a normal issue but recalculating them didn't yield anything.

[Here is the object in perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3KfE.jpg) and [here is the object in orhto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8xhl.jpg)

Comment: yes, weird, could you please share the file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots it is shared here: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6539" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6539/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the 3D View *N* panel > *View* > View > decrease the *Clipping End*, it was a bit too high (don't know why it has this effect though).

[image]

Comment: That worked! Thanks!